# Exporting File Geodatabase Raster license-free to TIFF or IMG

Tags: gdal, file-geodatabase, geotiff-tiff

Is there a license-free technology that can export rasters from an ESRI File Geodatabase to a file-based raster (e.g. GeoTIFF or IMG file)?

- Esri has the [FileGDB API](http://www.esri.com/apps/products/download/index.cfm?fuseaction=#File_Geodatabase_API_1.3) for "reading" the contents of a file geodatabase, but it has very few features for rasters.
- GDAL has some extensions for file geodatabase, but I've been unable to find one that can export the rasters.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that there is no license-free technology that can export rasters from a File Geodatabase to a file-based raster because, as @Vince comments:

> The File GDB API is read/write for simple feature classes, and
>   read-only for most vector feature classes. There is no raster support
>   in FGDBAPI.DLL. ArcObjects is your only API for reading FGDB rasters.