# Import gSSURGO gridded data to QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, file-geodatabase, ubuntu

How do I view the gridded data provided by gSSURGO in QGIS?

Following the instructions here ([File Geodatabase (*.gdb) support in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26285/file-geodatabase-gdb-support-in-qgis)), I'm able to import the vector data and tables with no problem but can't figure out how to locate or import the gridded (raster) layer.

Can this be done?

I am running QGIS 2.8.6-Wien on Ubuntu LTS 16.04.

Comment: It looks like the answer to my question is "no".  This is based on the comment in response to this question here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/167590/export-file-geodatabase-raster-to-tiff-or-img

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late but hopefully this answer helps someone else. The raster layer in contained within the Geodatabase file provided by NRCS. However, at the time of me writing this QGIS cannot open raster files contained within Geodatabases. It has to do with ESRI's API. Here's more on that topic [Opening Raster stored in Esri Geodatabase using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/110533/opening-raster-stored-in-esri-geodatabase-using-qgis)

Attempting to access the same raster data I ended up using ArcGIS Pro to open the raster and then exported it to a standalone GeoTiff which could then be opened in QGIS.